# What does this javascript event handler do?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to extract event handlers for forms submission.
For one website I got this handler which is very weird:
My question is what does this handler do and more importantly is it part of some 
JSLibrary.

Here is a link to the web page:
http://www.nfl.com/fantasy/story/09000d5d817fb977/article/nfl.fantasy/story;s1=story;slot=top;url=story;nfl=ad;!category=;kw=;team=no;team=was;team=sd;team=nyg;team=ten;team=bal;conf=nfc;conf=afc;dvsn=ncs;dvsn=nce;dvsn=acw;dvsn=acs;dvsn=acn;plyr=matthew_ryan;plyr=anquan_boldin;plyr=derrick_mason;event=fantasy;tile=

It is the handler run when you try the email form on the top right which appears when you click Email button.

```
function q(a) {
  a = a || window.event;
  var b = a.target || a.srcElement, c, d;
  while (b && b.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== "a") {
      b = b.parentNode;
  }
  if (b && b.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "a" && b.href) {
      c = b.href.match(f);
      if (c) {
          var e = o(b.href);
          twttr.events.hub ? (d = new p(l.generateId(), b), l.add(d), n(e, b), twttr.events.trigger("click", {target:b, region:"intent", type:"click", data:{}})) : m(e), a.returnValue = !1, a.preventDefault && a.preventDefault();
      }
  }
```

}

Comment: A google search indicated it is related to [Twitter Web Intents](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/intents-events)

Answer (score 0):

No, the only library it uses is Twitter's. The rest is fairly straightforward JavaScript, although the variable and function names are minified so it's hard to read.

```
function q(a) {
  // Get the event from the passed argument if it exists,
  // otherwise use the current event in the window
  a = a || window.event;

  // Get the target or source of the event, initialize variables c and d
  var b = a.target || a.srcElement, c, d;

  // Keep moving to the parent node of the target until you reach an <a> node
  while (b && b.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== "a") {
      b = b.parentNode;
  }

  // Double-check that b is an <a> node, then that
  // it has an href attribute, making it a link
  if (b && b.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "a" && b.href) {
      // f is unknown, but I assume here it matches the URL in the <a> tag
      // against some regular expression to make sure it's valid
      c = b.href.match(f);
      if (c) {
          // Extract the URL
          var e = o(b.href);

          // Send it on to Twitter if possible, otherwise just cancel
          // the click event
          twttr.events.hub ? (d = new p(l.generateId(), b), l.add(d), n(e, b),
            twttr.events.trigger("click", {target:b, region:"intent",
            type:"click", data:{}})) :
            m(e), a.returnValue = !1,
            a.preventDefault && a.preventDefault();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer
I actually meant if you can recognize a pattern for some library code. To clarify more: do you think that this code is some code from some javascript library to handle click events. I am saying this cause it seems a general code to handle any click event as the form does not have anything to do with what is going on here.
It is also coming from a file called widgets.js
Thanks again

Comment: Yeah, it's from the Twitter API (as opposed to a framework like jQuery or YUI). What it's designed to do is pass click events on to Twitter if a valid link tag is found, otherwise it doesn't do anything and doesn't disturb the user. It's part of the page that lets you tweet it, not anything else. It's not really part of form submission either, by the way. From the looks of the code it seems like it's just littering the page with a bunch of click events, and then testing afterward whether they're related to a Twitter button.